# checking the format of a field in a json file contaning a large date

Tags: json, excel, python-3.x, notepad++

I have a JSON file with 30000 lines. The file contains the data as shown below. I want to check if the "Date of Birth" field follows the same format everywhere. There is a  very large number of entries containing "Date of  Birth". May I know if there is a way throught notepad++, or python or any other tool or some way that I can check if  "Date of birth" is in same format. I want to make sure that the "Date of birth" section should not conntains date as "Mar 20, 2018" or "20/03/1989" or any other format other than "mm-dd-yyyy"

```
{
    "StudentInfo": {
        "Name": "John",
        "Date of Birth": "03-25-1991",
          },
        {
        "Name": "Timothy",
        "Date of Birth": "10-16-1989",
        },
     .
     .
     .
     .
        {
        "Name": "Alisha",
        "Date of Birth": "04-28-1992",
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

At first I would change the JSON structure. In my opinion your actual structure can't be deserialized to a python variable. Value of "StudentInfo" key must be a list of dictionaries identified with "[]" symbols.

```
{
"StudentInfo": [{
    "Name": "John",
    "Date of Birth": "03-25-1991",
      },
    {
    "Name": "Timothy",
    "Date of Birth": "10-16-1989",
    },
 .
 .
 .
 .
    {
    "Name": "Alisha",
    "Date of Birth": "04-28-1992",
    }]
   }
```

Then I would use both **json** and **re** modules:

```
import json
import re
```

I would define a simple regular expression checking the desired pattern (expression can be of course more complex to check that date is a real coherent date):

```
regex = re.compile(r"^(\d{2}\-){2}\d{4}$")
```

And run the following script (for example) printing students with a non-compliant date of birth:

```
with open("somejsonfile") as stream:
    mydict = json.load(stream)
    for subdict in mydict["StudentInfo"]:
        dob = subdict.get("Date of Birth")
        if dob:
            match = regex.match(dob)
            if not match:
                print("{dob} is not coherent for {name}".format(dob=dob, name=subdict["Name"]))
```